# attempting to verify a webhook secret with hmac and sha256

Tags: signature, sha256, hmac

so I am a little confused here.

I am using a api that sends a webhook to my server. It allows us to verify the request came from the api.

I am using django rest framework.

the signature comes over like this as an example

`Mux-Signature: t=1565220904,v1=20c75c1180c701ee8a796e81507cfd5c932fc17cf63a4a55566fd38da3a2d3d2` 
the value after the t= is a time stamp. The value after v1= is the signature

```
muxsecurityheader = request.META['HTTP_MUX_SIGNATURE']
        spiltmuxsecurityheader = muxsecurityheader.split(',')
        timestamp = spiltmuxsecurityheader[0]
        timestamp = timestamp[2:]
        receviedsignature = spiltmuxsecurityheader[1]
        receviedsignature = receviedsignature[3:]
        secretkey = 'a string that is my key'
        payload = timestamp + '.' + str(request.body)
        expectedsignature = hmac.new(secretkey, bytes(payload, 'UTF-8'), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
        print(expectedsignature)
```

is the code I have so far.

in an example on the apis docs https://docs-legacy.mux.com/docs/webhook-security

it states to determine the expected signature by the provided example. Obviously this is just pseudocode

```
secret = // your signing secret
payload = timestamp + "." + request_body
expected_signature = createHmacSha256(payload, secret)
```

which is similar to the code I have above.

however I am getting a few errors and

```
expectedsignature = hmac.new(secretkey, bytes(payload, 'UTF-8'), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
raise TypeError("key: expected bytes or bytearray, but got %r" % type(key).__name__)
TypeError: key: expected bytes or bytearray, but got 'str'
```

is one of them.

for example is one that I am trying to solve. And Im at the point where one of you is going to instantly see what It is I am doing wrong. I really appreciate you providing some clarity.

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution. I need to turn stuff into bytes!

```
muxsecurityheader = request.META['HTTP_MUX_SIGNATURE']
        spiltmuxsecurityheader = muxsecurityheader.split(',')
        timestamp = spiltmuxsecurityheader[0]
        timestamp = timestamp[2:]
        receviedsignature = spiltmuxsecurityheader[1]
        receviedsignature = receviedsignature[3:]
        secretkey = 'the secret key that they gave me and stuff'
        payload = bytes(timestamp, "UTF-8") + bytes('.','UTF-8') + request.body
        expectedsignature = hmac.new(bytes(secretkey, 'UTF-8'), payload, hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
        if expectedsignature == receviedsignature:
            print('yay')
```